# Update is ignoring the Limit clause

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Gorm doesn't seem to support the use of Limit with Update, and doesn't throw an error either.

```
resUpdate := tx.Model(&daos.Voucher{}).
            Where("status = ?", models.VoucherStatusAvailable).
            Limit(quantity).
                        Scan(&vouchers).
            Update("status", models.VoucherStatusBooked)
```

This query will update every field in my DB from VoucherStatusAvailable to VoucherStatusBooked, without regards for the use of Limit.

Someone quickly addressed the subject here : https://penkovski.com/post/gorm-update-returning/
But their solution of putting the Limit in the Where clause :

```
resUpdate := tx.Model(&daos.Voucher{}).
            Where("status = ? LIMIT ?", models.VoucherStatusAvailable, quantity).
            Update("status", models.VoucherStatusBooked)
```

doesn't work when using gorm soft delete, since it put parentheses around the where clause, and the `AND deleted_at = NULL` filter after it.

Initially I was doing it with two separated query (a select then an update) but in this case there is a chance of conflict.
Does anyone have an idea of how I should do the selection of X members of the table, then update their status, without having a risk of conflict with the selected items ?

Edit : The DBMS I'm using is PostgreSQL

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Hello, we are using postgresql

Comment: Postgres doesn't support the `LIMIT` clause in `UPDATE` query.

Comment: *"Does anyone have an idea of how I should do the selection of X members of the table, then update their status, without having a risk of conflict with the selected items ?"* -- You can use CTEs. Basically in the CTE you can do select the ids of those rows that you are interested in and there you can use the limit clause, then in the primary statement you can do the update using a `WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cte)` clause. https://postgresql.org/docs/15/interactive/queries-with.html

Comment: I don't use gorm so I don't know how *exactly* you can do CTEs with it but it seems to be possible, try looking through these search results: https://github.com/search?q=language%3Ago+gorm+cte&type=code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different point were answered :

1. Postgre doesn't support LIMIT and ORDER BY, so I needed an alternative.
2. The right alternative seemed to be CTEs, as pointed out in a comment.
3. gorm support custom plugin, and there is a plugin that implement CTE : https://github.com/WinterYukky/gorm-extra-clause-plugin. Unfortunately, it isn't compatible with the Update clause.
4. So ultimately, the only solution I found is to do a CTE in raw SQL :

```golang
        var updated []Voucher
        resUpdate := tx.Raw(`WITH v AS (
            SELECT * from vouchers WHERE status = ?
            LIMIT ?
        )
        UPDATE vouchers SET status = ?
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM v WHERE vouchers.id = v.id)
        RETURNING *`,
        models.ArticleStatusAvailable, quantity, models.VoucherStatusBooked).
        Scan(&updated)
```